# Power Query: Index adjustment solution

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have multiple tables with index column and some matching ids. I need to combine all tables in one with adjusted index by applying ratio between matching ids.

The first step (the yellow one) is simple: we multiply Table2 index on ratio of fist 2 initial tables. The hard part is the next step (the reddish one): we need to find ratio between matching id of Table3 and the previously adjusted id of Table2.

Is there a creative way you can make this in Power Query?

See image below:

[image: Please see the image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red index is simply

```
(100/82)*(88/100) = 88/82 = 1.07317
```

You can continue this pattern with more tables. For example, with five tables, your last index would be:

```
(Index of Max Table1 id)/(Index of Min Table2 id) *
(Index of Max Table2 id)/(Index of Min Table3 id) *
(Index of Max Table3 id)/(Index of Min Table4 id) *
(Index of Max Table4 id)/(Index of Min Table5 id)
```

Comment: Alexis you are right, only there is a coinsidence with min/max here and it would be rather ratio between values of matching ids.